# Laravel 5.2 composer update

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

When I try to run a composer command like `composer update` it will throw an error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files


  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not scan for classes inside "tests/TestCase.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder                                                  


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I try to require a package `Image`

> http://image.intervention.io

I'm using Laravel 5.2 on OSX 10.11.5 with PHP 5.6.

---

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "paynl/sdk": "^1.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "milon/barcode": "^5.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Veluwade\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your composer.json file?

Comment: Did you edit or remove `tests/TestCase.php`?

Comment: I added `composer.json`. Ps, I didn't remove `tests/TestCade.php`, I don't know where to find it.

Comment: If it does not exist, remove the `autoload-dev`->`classmap` entry for it

Comment: @tkausl I removed it and before it works, I ran `composer dumpautoload`. After that I could run `composer update`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit or removed the TestCase.php file in the tests folder?? OR edited the app.php in the bootstrap folder??

If it is edited, revert back and then check.